# Git stash -u hanging on specific repo

Tags: git

I'm running `git stash -u` (to stash all files, including untracked) in an specific repository and it's freezing the console.

It works in other repositories tough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, it was because I had an untracked database dump (10GB), and with `git stash -u` git was adding it to the stash commit, which was taking a huge amount of time. Removing that huge file made it work instantaneously.

Comment: In other words, it's not actually *hanging*, it's just spending a lot of time compressing 10 GB into the frozen format that Git would put in the commit (remember, `git stash` just means *make some commits, on no branches, then clear out the state I just committed*).